# USB-to-Serial device, why no /dev entry?

Tags: usb, serial-port

I initially asked this question on SU but it is so specific to Ubuntu that I move it here.

I installed [an 433Mhz transceiver](http://dx.com/p/usb-1100pa-433mhz-wireless-rf-transceiver-module-white-black-159139) on my Ubuntu system (3.8.0-35). It is an USB-to-Serial kind of device and is somehow recognized:

`dmesg` output:

```
[  324.051498] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  324.088070] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=8668
[  324.088081] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  324.088087] usb 3-1: Product: NETUSB1100 NEWMSG 
[  324.088093] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: HZWB
[  324.102259] hid-generic 0003:10C4:8668.0002: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Device [HZWB NETUSB1100 NEWMSG ] on usb-0000:0e:00.0-1/input0
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 10c4:8668 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
```

I would like to access it (via [rfxcmd](https://code.google.com/p/rfxcmd/) for instance) but I cannot get a relevant `/dev` path. The contents of `/dev` do not change when I plug it in so there is certainly something missing.

What other steps must be done in order to create a `/dev/...` device path - which can be then used in scripts?

**EDIT** after [lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/users/6969/lekensteyn)'s answer: output of `tree /sys/bus/usb/drivers/` following a `modprobe cp210x` (with non-relevant parts removed). Please note that following a reboot the `3-1` above became a `3-2` below. I took that into account in the tests.

```
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/
├── cp210x
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/usbserial
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
├── hub
│   ├── 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
│   ├── 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
│   ├── 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
│   ├── 2-1:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
│   ├── 3-0:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
│   ├── 4-0:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/usbcore
│   ├── new_id
│   ├── remove_id
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
├── usb
│   ├── 1-1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1
│   ├── 1-1.2 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
│   ├── 1-1.3 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
│   ├── 1-1.4 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
│   ├── 1-1.6 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6
│   ├── 2-1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1
│   ├── 3-2 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-2
│   ├── bind
│   ├── uevent
│   ├── unbind
│   ├── usb1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1
│   ├── usb2 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2
│   ├── usb3 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3
│   └── usb4 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb4
├── usbhid
│   ├── 1-1.2:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0
│   ├── 3-2:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/usbhid
│   ├── new_id
│   ├── remove_id
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
├── usbserial
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/usbserial
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
├── usbserial_generic
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/usbserial
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
```

EDIT: added `dmesg` after cp210x.ko recompilation and reboot (with the new cp210x.ko)

```
[    1.352918] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.389854] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=8668
[    1.389865] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.389871] usb 3-2: Product: NETUSB1100 NEWMSG 
[    1.389877] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: HZWB
[    1.399869] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.399872] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.406870] hid-generic 0003:10C4:8668.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Device [HZWB NETUSB1100 NEWMSG ] on usb-0000:0e:00.0-2/input0
```

after a manual `modprobe cp210x`, the extra lines in `dmesg`.

```
[ 1313.312593] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[ 1313.312642] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[ 1313.312674] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[ 1313.329536] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[ 1313.329575] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
(end of file)
```

Comment: did you ever manage to communicate with your device through the ttyUSB channel? When following the steps above and below, I had a ttyUSB0 device, but when trying to read from it, I recieved an error in dmesg: cp210x_open - Unable to enable UART

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the generic HID drivers owns a device, it makes clear that a more specific driver is missing for the device. I grepped the kernel tree (3.13) for your device (`10[Cc]4` and `8668`), but did not find a driver for this. The closest I found was the `cp210x` module, but it has no entry for your `8668` device.

You can try to manually bind the device to the `cp210x` driver (Change `3-1` to the addresses listed in `dmesg`):

```
sudo modprobe cp210x
sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind <<<3-1
sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cp210x/bind <<<3.1
```

---

Try editing the cp210x module and add your product ID to the list:

```
apt-get source linux-headers-$(uname -r)
cd linux-lts-*/drivers/usb/serial
wget https://gist.github.com/Lekensteyn/8544581/raw/cp210x-10c4-8668.patch
patch < cp210x-10c4-8668.patch
```

If you do not want to fetch 124MB of sources, all you need are the Makefile and cp210x.c files. See https://gist.github.com/Lekensteyn/8544581 for already patched versions based on 3.8.0-35-generic.

Then build the module (install the `build-essential` package using `apt-get` if you have not already):

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) M=$PWD cp210x.ko
```

Then unload the old module (if any) and load the newly built one (you need to disable Secure Boot if you had it enabled):

```
sudo rmmod cp210x
sudo insmod cp210x.ko
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. `cp210x` is likely to be the good choice as I found out from some documentation. I tried the manual bind but i) I had to give a more explicit device for the unbind part (`sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind <<<"3-1:1.0"`) and ii) I could not bind manually, the commnand returns a `tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cp210x/bind: No such device`. I updated my question with a `tree` of `/sys/bus/usb/drivers` immediately follwing the `modprobe`.

Comment: Note: Following a reboot the 3-1 in the two first listings became a 3-2 in the `tree`output. I used the correct one in the tests (and will update the question).

Comment: One more thing: I tried to re-bind the device to `usbhid` right after unbinding it , it worked (back to the same tree layout than before the unbind). In that case I really have no idea why the same command on `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/cp210x/bind` does not work

Comment: @WoJ See edit, can you test that out?

Comment: I patched and compiled the file per your instructions - the .ko module compiled and can be loaded fine. Unfortunately this does not generate any new entry in `/dev`, `dmesg` shows two extra lines: `usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x`and `usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x`. I unlugged / plugged the device, loaded / unloaded the module in all combinations but it still looks like there is no link between the device and the cp210x driver

Comment: @WoJ My bad, I did not apply the patch yet to the cp210x.c source in that gist. Please try again (or apply the patch yourself).

Comment: I did apply the patch myself, the `{ USB_DEVICE(0x10C4, 0x8668) }, /* USB-1100PA 433MHz Wireless RF Transceiver Module */` is in `cp210x.c`, which I compiled to `cp210x.ko` (then `insmod` and even replaced the original one in `/usr/lib...` with the compiled one to run a `modprobe`). Is there a way to check what are the devices supported by the currently-loaded driver? (to make absolutely sure that one is in, though I triple-checked)

Comment: Try `modinfo cp210x | grep 8668` (look for the aliases, `v[VENDOR]p[PRODUCT]...`. Can you add your dmesg tail to the question?

Comment: done. I do not see changes (rebooted with the new `cp210x.ko` which replaced the stock one). I issued a manual `modprobe cp210x` and attached the extra lines in dmesg. I also checked for the driver with your command and I get `alias: usb:v10C4p8668d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*`so it is in.

Comment: It still does not result in a `/dev/ttyUSB*` file? Perhaps another driver (`usbhid`) owns the device, and you need to employ the unbind trick described here? Use the `ls -dl /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.1:1.2/driver` command to find out the driver name.

Comment: YES - that was it. I forgot to unbind from `usbhid`. After reloading the module I have a `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Thank you very, very much for the extended help!

Answer (score 0):

I use shell scripts to manage identifying device node and use custom cp210x driver. The also give appropriate udev rules and scripts to dynamically execute a script when a CP210X device is hot plugged.

github.com/RishiGupta12/serial-communication-manager/tree/master/drivers/cp210x-silicon-labs