# Usb to Serial Cable adapter, recognized but not attached to a /dev/tty*

Tags: usb, serial-port, dmesg

I have a USB-to-RS232 converter cable, the cable is proven to work in Windows machines, Ubuntu detects it but does not attach the converter to any /dev/tty.

I tried connecting it to USB 2.0 and 3.0, nothing.

Does not sow any error or anything.

The OS is Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel: 5.4.0-66-generic running on a 10th gen Intel i5, 8GB DDR4 RAM, Aorus ULTRA Z490I

"dmesg" tells me that it is in the system, but it's not attached to anything.

```
[12811.723685] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[12811.872472] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=23c3, bcdDevice= 3.05
[12811.872474] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12811.872474] usb 1-4: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[12811.872475] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[12811.872476] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: EFA>f103Y23
```

"lsusb" shows that it is in fact detected

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 067b:23c3 Prolific Technology, Inc. USB-Serial Controller
```

"usb-devices" shows this:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=04 Dev#=  8 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=067b ProdID=23c3 Rev=03.05
S:  Manufacturer=Prolific Technology Inc.
S:  Product=USB-Serial Controller
S:  SerialNumber=EFA>f103Y23
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

Edit:

I have an Ubuntu Laptop (It's the same Windows machine as tested it before but booted into Ubuntu) with same OS and Kernel, dmesg shows that It is detected and attached to ttyUSB0

```
[   77.810199] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   77.959158] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=23c3, bcdDevice= 3.05
[   77.959163] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   77.959166] usb 3-2: Product: USB-Serial Controller 
[   77.959169] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc. 
[   77.959171] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: EFA>f103Y23
[   78.122784] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   78.122793] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   78.127135] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[   78.127145] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[   78.127169] pl2303 3-2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[   78.127337] usb 3-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Have you seen https://askubuntu.com/questions/408627/usb-to-serial-device-why-no-dev-entry?rq=1 ?

Comment: I’m not sure my experience is relevant in this case. But there are many USB-RS232/Serial/DB-9 adapter with a clone of Prolific chip. As it seems, Prolific is fighting them by tuning its driver to work with original adapters only. In MS Windows I could get them working using a patched version of driver. I tried some adapters with Ubuntu probably 18.04, they worked fine in loop test. If it is possible try them in a live Ubuntu 18.04 or virtual box, to confirm if there is regression in 20.04.

Comment: Have you tried to list it with `ls -lo /dev/ttyUSB0*` in a terminal ?

Comment: @MarkWilliams yes, I did, but since my other Ubuntu computer where it works has the same OS and Kernel, I didn't think It could be drivers.

Comment: @user.dz Tried it on another Ubuntu Computer and It worked fine, same OS, Same Kernel

Comment: @SorenA Yes, It does appear a device, BUT it's an RPLIDAR, It does work. It's a  Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge.

Comment: `lsmod | grep serial` show something?

Comment: @nobody yes. lsmod shows this:
`usbserial              53248  3 cp210x`

It shows the cp2110x used in the RPLIDAR that I have in the system.

Comment: Hm `sudo modprobe -rv cp210x`  then try `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x067b product=0x23c3`

Answer (score 0):

```
# modprobe -rv usbserial
rmmod usbserial
# modprobe -v usbserial vendor=0x067b product=0x23c3
insmod /lib/modules/4.19.94-ti-r42/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko.xz vendor=0x067b product=0x23c3
# ls -lh /dev/ttyUSB0 
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jan  9 18:26 /dev/ttyUSB0
```